# Do you know if it exists some documentation for Xcode 4 project templates 

Tags: xcode4

I started to work on a custum project template for Xcode 4. I found this two links :
 - http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/
 - http://snipt.net/yonishin/about-xcode-4-project-template

It helps to start but I do not manage to implement things like :
 - add another Xcode project as a target dependency,
 - add a group into another group.

Any idea how to do such things, or where I could find some documentations ?

Regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to add target dependencies yet but I've created a [post to answer you subgroups issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445640/creating-sub-groups-in-xcode-4-templates). litte-buddy got the answer.

Hope this helps for this part at least.

Regards,

Johan

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug:

[Unofficial Xcode 4 Template Documentation](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/xcode4-template-documentation/)

I've put in roughly 70 hours to document the Xcode 4 template system as good as is possible with trial and error. It's 70 pages plus several example templates. I charge a small fee for it because it's extensive and I put a lot of time into it.

I was most interested in figuring a way to add other Xcode projects to a project template, that actually got the documentation effort started.

Unfortunately, all my tests did point to one conclusion: Apple never intended for project templates to use or create additional project references. You can add a .xcodeproj file to the project template, but the new project template format unfortunately doesn't allow you to copy files without adding them to the newly created project. In essence I would say that creating project templates referencing other Xcode projects may be possible but not in a satisfactory way (speak: no manual cleanup by user of the newly created project). At least not to me.

Comment: This is worth buying, it saved me a lot of time.