# How to add folder reference in XCode 4 Project Template

Tags: xcode4, project-template

i have some problems about adding folder reference in xcode 4 project template, i just can add Groups and Sub Groups to project. does anyone successed doing this? please share here..

here's the code that i use to add Group:

```
<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>main.h</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>main.h</string>
        <key>Group</key>
            <string>css</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<key>Nodes</key>
<array>
    <string>main.h</string>
</array>
```

that code just generate Group not a Folder Reference...please help me

*sorry my english a bit strange, haha

Comment: Did you find a way to reference a folder rather than copy all files locally?

Comment: hi! Any solution on this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your file to be added to a folder, then you should reference it with its full desired path everywhere you define it (namely in the definitions and in the nodes section)

```
<key>Definitions</key>
  <dict> 
    <key>css/main.h</key>
     <dict>
       <key>Path</key>
       <string>main.h</string>
       <key>Group</key>
       <string>css</string>
     </dict>

<key>Nodes</key>
 <array>
  <string>css/main.h</string>
 </array>
```