# Creating iPhone Project Template for XCode 4

Tags: iphone, templates, project

How does one create a re-usable Project Template for XCode that will show up as an option for me to start development of a new Project?

I've hunted down several web pages and blogs and I can't seem to make this work too well. I've tried a number of instructions around the web but can't get my template to show up in XCode no matter what I do... what's the secret?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this article http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/. It has an impressive amount of detail on the process of creating an XCode 4 project template. Also, make sure to check out the comment section at the bottom of the article, quiet a few people have added notes and details.

Answer (score 0):

Having the template show up in Xcode shouldn't be too difficult. The important thing is for the template files to be in your user template folders location. For example:

```
/Users/user728651/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates
```

Under that folder create a new folder called - for example - `"My Templates"`

Then, copy one of the default templates across to the new "My Templates" folder. For example, try copying the iOS Master-Detail template from:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Application/Master-Detail
```

to:

```
/Users/user728651/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/My Templates
```

When you select New Project in Xcode, you will then see:

[image]

Also worth a look, with links to more examples is the answer to this question:

[Creating sub-groups in XCode 4 Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445640/creating-sub-groups-in-xcode-4-templates)

Comment: Should this still work on Xcode 6, because I can not get it to work