# Create empty group in Xcode 7 template

Tags: ios, xcode, templates, xcode-template

I try to create a Xcode template. I followed the question [Xcode 4 template create empty group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535328/xcode-4-template-create-empty-group) but it doesn't work anymore.

There is only a file called "Application" (without an extension).

**TemplateInfo.plist**

```
<key>Nodes</key>
<array>
    <string>Application</string>
</array>

<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>Application</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>Application</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

**Current result:**

[image: Project structure]

**Expected result:**

[image: Expected result]

How do I have to change the **TemplateInfo.plist** so Xcode generates an empty folder called *Application* and not a file without an extension?

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @StuartP. I've updated the question and added the expected result

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 8, I wanted to add an empty group for to ensure the template follows a specific scaffolding. Through trial and error, I achieved this by I adding an empty folder in the xctemplate directory, and then configured the node / definition accordingly. I hope this helps :)

[image]

```
<key>Nodes</key>
<array>
    <string>Application</string>
</array>

<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>Application</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>Application/</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: This creates a yellow folder? And not a blue folder?

Comment: @ColdLogic this creates Blue folder

Comment: @blyscuit Any idea how to make it yellow?

Answer (score -1):

**Xcode 8**

You could create folders inside .xctemplate directory. After creating files from that template, the folders that you've created will be shown as real folders, not groups, so...

You can simply just remove reference to all of those files and add them again to your project (with create groups from folders option selected).