# Create subgroups into xcode 7 template

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, templates

I'm making a xcode template with swift files but I want to divide these files in groups:

```
> Group (file template name)
> --- Group One
> ------ swiftFile
> ------ swiftFile
> ------ swiftFile
> --- Group Two
> ------ swiftFile
> ------ swiftFile
```

Can you help me? Can you also create folders module, that refer to these groups?

Comment: I prefer create the folders on my project and then add this folder to xcode creating a group

Comment: I have a Template, that contains few files and when I create new Template file with Xcode, all files of template are contained in a group

Comment: Did you find http://stackoverflow.com/a/5561131/2185 ?