# Creating groups using a custom template xcode 8

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode8, xcode-template

I have successfully created an Xcode 8 template that will respond to these actions:

1. You already have a working project
2. You want to add your custom swift file to this project

**Step by step, how to achieve that:**

I have created under:

```
/Users/*YOUR_USER_NAME*/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates
```

The folder name `Custom/Interactor.xctemplate`

Files inside that folder:

- ___FILEBASENAME___Interactor
- TemplateInfo.plist
- TemplateIcon.png
- TemplateIcon@2x.png

So when I right click and create new file, I will choose the custom file:

[image: create new file]

[image: Creating custom file]

The above example works and creates my custom file:

[image: successfully creating a custom file]

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I am trying to create a group that will contain the new custom file. No need for an actual folder or complicated tasks, simply a group that contains the actual file.

So the end result will be:

[image]

Since there is no documentation explaining how to create a custom template I have used many references: [ref1](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-create-custom-project-templates-in-xcode-7), [ref2](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/creating-custom-xcode-templates), [ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445640/creating-sub-groups-in-xcode-4-templates?noredirect=1&lq=1), [ref4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445640/creating-sub-groups-in-xcode-4-templates).

Here is the `TemplateInfo.plist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>DefaultCompletionName</key>
    <string>MyCustomInteractor</string>
  <key>Description</key>
  <string>Custom interactor</string>
  <key>Kind</key>
  <string>Xcode.IDEKit.TextSubstitutionFileTemplateKind</string>
  <key>Options</key>
  <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>Custom interactor</string>
            <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>fileName</string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Custom name</string>
            <key>NotPersisted</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Required</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>text</string>
        </dict>
    <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <string>___VARIABLE_fileName:identifier___</string>
            <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>productName</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>static</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <string>___VARIABLE_fileName:identifier___Interactor</string>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>The interactor name</string>
            <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>interactorName</string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Interactor Name:</string>
            <key>Required</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>static</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
  <key>Platforms</key>
  <array>
        <string>com.apple.platform.iphoneos</string>
  </array>
    <key>SortOrder</key>
    <string>99</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to insert [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445640/creating-sub-groups-in-xcode-4-templates) answer into my TemplateInfo.plist but nothing happens. In my opinion it could be related to a scope issue - perhaps I am not inserting the `Definitions` or the `Nodes` keys in the right place. The xml `Definitions` and `Nodes` code snip I have been struggling with:

```
<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>___FILEBASENAME___Interactor.swift</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Group</key>
        <string>Custom Interactor</string>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>___FILEBASENAME___Interactor.swift</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<key>Nodes</key>
<array>
    <string>___FILEBASENAME___Interactor.swift</string>
</array>
```

So where should I insert those keys or what am I doing wrong ?

**Any** help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly same problem here... it seems `Definitions` and `Nodes` are only taken into account for project templates, and adding the file into a folder in the Template makes XCode to import the folder instead of creating a group...

Comment: I have reached to the same conclusion

Comment: have you managed to do group template?

Comment: @wm.p1us, Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I found group template (clean-swift.com) and will try to use it for example. May be it will be useful for you as well.

Comment: @wm.p1us, Creating a group template when creating a new project IS possible, but creating a bunch of files and group them in an existing project isn't possible at this moment unless you will show me otherwise :)

Comment: If you try add scene (from clean-swift) you will see that it is not one file but 7 at once.

Comment: Which is exactly what I have asked in this thread and need...

Comment: @OhadM any luck with this?

Comment: @George, unfortunately no. It seems that it is only possible when creating a new project - still looking for a hack/solution :)

Comment: @OhadM Please do post answer if you find

Comment: I would like to know as well

Comment: Yep, over here in 2020--still looking for an answer to this...Apple should really document this.

Comment: 2021: still looking =)

Comment: Yes I am :) Perhaps Apple will give us the solution in near Xcode version

Answer (score 1):

You can create groups as well as folders in the project directory using a `Nodes` dictionary:

```xml
<key>Swift</key>
<dict>
    <key>Nodes</key>
    <array>
         <string>ViewController.swift:comments</string>
         <string>ViewController.swift:imports:importCocoa</string>
         <string>ViewController.swift:implementation(___FILEBASENAME___: UIViewController)</string>
         <string>ViewController.swift:implementation:methods:viewDidLoad(override func viewDidLoad(\))</string>
         <string>ViewController.swift:implementation:methods:viewDidLoad:super</string>
         <string>ViewController.swift:implementation:methods:didReceiveMemoryWarning(override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(\))</string>
         <string>ViewController.swift:implementation:methods:didReceiveMemoryWarning:super</string>
         <string>Constant/CommonExtension.swift</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

You'll also need to supply `Definitions`, just like this:

```xml
<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>Base.lproj/Main.storyboard</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>Main.storyboard</string>
        <key>SortOrder</key>
        <integer>99</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>Group</key>
    <array>
        <string>Singletone</string>
    </array>
    <key>Constant/CommonExtension.swift</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>Constant/CommonExtension.swift</string>
        <key>Group</key>
        <array>
            <string>Constant</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Does this works on an existing project or only when creating a new project ?

Comment: this is work with new project with our custom template

Comment: Thanks but I am aware that it works for a new project. I am looking for a solution of an existing project

Comment: @PratikLad do you know how to set a SortOrder to a Group?

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone, here's a project template that works with Xcode 12.4:

```xml
<key>Nodes</key>
<array>
    <string>ViewController.swift:comments</string>
    <string>ViewController.swift:imports:importCocoa</string>
    <string>ViewController.swift:implementation(___FILEBASENAME___: UIViewController)</string>
    <string>ViewController.swift:implementation:methods:viewDidLoad(override func viewDidLoad(\))</string>
    <string>ViewController.swift:implementation:methods:viewDidLoad:super</string>
    <string>Info.plist:UIMainStoryboardFile</string>
    <string>Info.plist:UIApplicationSceneManifest:UISceneStoryboardFile</string>
    <string>Some/MainCoordinator.swift</string>
    <string>Some/Other/TestClass.swift</string>
</array>
<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>Some/MainCoordinator.swift</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Group</key>
        <array>
            <string>Some</string>
        </array>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>MainCoordinator.swift</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Some/Other/TestClass.swift</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Group</key>
        <array>
            <string>Some</string>
            <string>Other</string>
        </array>
        <key>Path</key>
        <string>TestClass.swift</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The group is `Some`. There's a file inside it. There's also a subgroup inside it called `Other`. And there's a file inside `Other` called `TestClass`.

---

#### The Result

[image: Screenshot of the Xcode file navigator showing a top-level folder, Some, with a nested file and folder, Other.]

Comment: how do you include more than one file in a single group?

Comment: Where should Definitions and Nodes be? In the root?