# add project template in xcode 4.0.1

Tags: iphone, templates, ios4, xcode4, project-template

I have created one project template and I am able to place it in xcode 3 but its now showing up in the xcode 4. Please let me know if is there any difference in placing the template.

I have copied my project template in the ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4 made major changes to project templates. This means Xcode 3 project templates do not work in Xcode 4. There is very little documentation on the new project templates, which makes creating Xcode 4 project templates difficult. The following question has links to the best documentation currently available for creating Xcode 4 project templates:

[Do you know if it exists some documentation for Xcode 4 project templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343077/do-you-know-if-it-exists-some-documentation-for-xcode-4-project-templates)